# Find and map together data in an Array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to map and gather the name - sum values from an array, but I don't know what the best solution would be here and I got stuck. The data that I get looks like this:

```
{
timestamp:"2022-09-15",
management: [
{ id: 1;
  name: Sam;
  sum: 12;
},
{ id: 2;
  name: Sam;
  sum: 20;
},
{ id: 3;
  name: Sam;
  sum: 30;
},
{ id: 4;
  name: Sam;
  sum: null;
},
{ id: 5;
  name: Mae;
  sum: 456;
}]
```

What I would like to achieve is this output:

```
this.labels = ["Sam", "Mae"];
this.sums = [ 62, 456];
```

So I would like to find and add all sum values that Sam has, and all values that Mae has, and gather them in an array. What would be the recommended way to do this? What I have tried:

```
interface FinancesUI {
  timestamp: string;
  management: ProductUI[];
}

interface ProductUI {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  sum: number;
}

finances: FinancesUI;
labels = string[];
sums = number[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.financesService.getProducts()
     .subscribe({
      next: (financesUI: FinancesUI) => {
        this.finances = financesUI;
        
        const allNames = this.finances.management.map((data) => data.name);
        const getSum = this.finances.management.map((data) => data.sum);
        this.labels = [...new Set(allNames)];

        this.finances.management.forEach((management, i = 0) => {
            if (management.name === this.labels[i]) {
              this.sums.push(management.sum);
            }
          })
      }, 
      error: (error) => {
        ...
    }
  });
  }
```

I get an error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". Can someone please help me?

Comment: where this `person` value coming from?

Comment: Posting your code into the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/) results in 37 errors. Please make sure your code reproduces the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking. groupBy name and then take the sum for each group.

```js
// like groupBy, but a bit more versatile due to the reducer.
function aggregate(list, getKey, reducer) {
  const map = new Map();
  for (const item of list) {
    const key = getKey(item);
    map.set(key, reducer(map.get(key), item));
  }
  return map;
}


const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Sam", sum: 12 },
  { id: 2, name: "Sam", sum: 20 },
  { id: 3, name: "Sam", sum: 30 },
  { id: 4, name: "Sam", sum: null },
  { id: 5, name: "Mae", sum: 456 }
];

const sumsByName = aggregate(
  data, 
  item => item.name, //group by Name
  (total=0, item) => total + (+item.sum)  // aggregate some value per group
);

console.log("labels", [...sumsByName.keys()]);
console.log("sums", [...sumsByName.values()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reduce
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
const {labels, sum} =  YOUR_OBJECT.management.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
const {name, sum} = curr;
const pos = acc.labels.indexOf(name)
if (pos === -1){
  acc.labels.push(name)
  acc.sums.push(sum)
} else {
  acc.sums[pos] += sum
}

return acc}, {labels: [], sums: []})
```

Something like this should work !

Answer (score 0):

> this.sums?.push(person.sum);

try adding {?} after sums

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).